# The countability of "champion"

Tags: articles, countability, countable-nouns

I saw two sentences on Google and on the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cap), under the definition of "cap":

> "he capped a memorable season by **becoming champion**" (Google, which should be getting its content from the ODO)
>
> ‘he capped a memorable season by **becoming champion of champions**’ (ODO)

I find these sentences odd, because according to both the Macmillan Dictionary and Cambridge English Dictionary, the word **champion** is a count noun. So shouldn't these sentences be:

> "he capped a memorable season by **becoming a champion**"
>
> ‘he capped a memorable season by **becoming the champion of champions**’

Comment: It seems like "champion" is being thought of as a title, though an informal one.

Comment: @user3169 This makes sense. Though I wonder if this could be said of a lot of cases. Does it mean the word is slowly taking on a mass noun usage?

Comment: One assumes the speaker  is referring to a particular position of honor that a lone competitor can come to occupy in a non-team sport like boxing.   A wide variety of nouns that can exist as plurals can be cast as roles without article; compare *He was mechanic to the Queen*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly in British English, when people have a role or appointment, that role is often written or spoken of without any article, definite or indefinite, even when it is a count noun. I am manager in this office. She was president. He became champion. Peter is Finance Officer. This usage is not informal or casual.